# Specflow run multiple environment

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow

As suggested I am rewording the question for clarification on requirements:

Suppose there are 4 environments (Development/Functional Test/Staging and Production). Each environment has its own database, Rest API (URI), username, password etc etc and there are two sets of tests

a) Continuous Integration tests that run as part of deployment (Run against Development and production)
b) Complete test suite (Run against Functional and Staging)

I want tests to pick up environment dynamically or It can be specified as command line argument to kick of the required tests.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about Urls I will assume you are running some sort of automated UI tests.

For a given `feature1.feature` Specflow generates a `C#` file called `feature1.feature.cs`, in this file there are tests written in the unit testing framework you have configured in your `App.config`. [Here](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Unit-test-providers/) are the available unit test providers.

When you run your tests from the command line, you are actually running those (let's say) `NUnit` tests. So you won't be able to get those arguments from the command line.

Comment: When using the Visual Studio old MSTest testrunner, you can select a testsettings file from the command line. In this testsettings file, you can provide a configuration file as deployement item. Using different configuration files in multiple testsetting files, you can differentiate between environments and users. When this question is reopened I will elaborate on that.